# How to create new file in specific folder from keyboard only?

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm

I found in the [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/populating-projects.html) that one can create a new file in PhpStorm by selecting a directory in the project tool window and pressing <kbd>Alt + Insert</kbd> to create the file.

I also found out that when I am writing stuff in a file and I want to create a new file in the same directory I can press <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + Insert</kbd> to create a new file in the same directory.

However, I wonder, if it is possible to create a new file in a different directory only with the keyboard, without having to use the mouse cursor and selecting the directory in the Project tool window.

I know that for Mac one may open a navigation bar using <kbd>Cmd + Up</kbd>, then one can type in the directory where one wants to create the new file and press <kbd>Cmd + N</kbd> to create the new file.
But how can I do this on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

When you are creating a new file (directly from that popup menu or via `Main Menu | File | New... | File`) you can enter **a relative path** as well.

For example: I'm on Windows. Current file is `ROOT\testing\debug\simple.php`.

If I will use that <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + Insert</kbd> and use `File` there, I can enter `..\..\new\123.txt` path and the new file `123.txt` file will be created in a `ROOT\new` folder (the `new` folder will be created if does not exist).

*P.S. Linux path delimiter works just fine even on Windows: `../../new/123.txt`.*

[image]

Final result:
[image]

*NOTE: the new file will not be focused/folder expanded in the Project View panel by default (unless you have activated "Always Select Opened File" option in Project View panel for that).*

---

Another approach: if you do not remember the folder structure, just **use Navigation Bar** to navigate there and then invoke <kbd>Alt + Insert</kbd> (shortcut for `File | New...`) from there: this action is context dependent and will use current context for the base file path:

<kbd>Alt + Home</kbd> (or whatever you may have there for `Navigate | Jump to Navigation Bar` action), navigate to the desired folder (use arrows, <kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter the sub folder) and then invoke <kbd>Alt + Insert</kbd> from there:

Start location:
[image]

Navigating to the desired target folder:
[image]

Invoking "New" menu popup:
[image]

Final result:
[image]

Comment: Okay I see. But having to enter the complete path or relational path is quite a pain. On Mac you could just enter fir example `angularjsDocs` and phpStorm would show all paths that contain this folder.

Comment: Yes, but you are trying to create new file and NOT select one from existing ones (like `Navigate | File` or alike). If you want: use `Navigate | File` -- it can show folders there as well. If you end your search with `/` it will navigate to that folder on `Enter` and then you can do the rest. But yes, there is no path completion functionality in `New | File` popup.